# Nvidia-settings doesn't detect my laptop screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS freshly installed on my laptop and using Nvidia driver 418.56 (Geforce GTX 660M). Everything is mostly fine, but there are a few settings I can't customize such as colour controls and digital vibrance.

I think the issue is that my driver doesn't "see" my laptop screen, and instead displays a message stating that PRIME displays cannot be controlled by nvidia-settings.

[Here's a picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujSKZ.png)

As you can see, there's a missing entry where the red arrow is pointing, which should be the monitor/screen that would allow me to configure these settings.

When I use the xrandr --query command, I get the following:
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
LVDS-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm

Anyone know what I should do to get control over these settings? Is there some other driver I should be using instead?

Thanks!